# Google Fabric: Time in App vs Session Length

Tags: google-fabric

Can anyone explain the difference between the "Time in App" vs "Session Length" metric?

The Time in App metric started showing up as a metric in May 2017 and is significantly higher than the Session Length metric, so they are clearly different, but it's not clear as to how.

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here. "Session length" is the median length across all daily active users. A session is considered complete when the app has been sent to the background for more than 30 seconds. Time in App" is a measure of how long the typical daily active user is active in the app on a specific day.

A user could, and often do, have multiple sessions in a day which would then be included in the time in app. For example, if I look at a calendar app for 30 seconds each time, I use, but I use it 6 times a day, then my time in app would be 3 minutes, but my session length would be 30 seconds.

Reference: https://docs.fabric.io/apple/answers/answers-metrics.html